# Add rotator function with Timing 10 seconds for this POPUP javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, popup

This script rotate 5 pop'up tags, display one pop'up for every webpage manual refresh. 
i want the script rotate automaticly one pop'up tag every 60 seconds.

if someone genius can make it i will be very grateful for him

Regards

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--  
var frequencyCap = 12; 
function setCookie(cookieName,cookieValue, expirehours) {
  if (frequencyCap > 0) {
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 10000 * frequencyCap);
    document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue) + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
  } else {
    document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue);
  }
}
function ReadCookie(cookieName) {
 var theCookie=""+document.cookie;
 var ind=theCookie.indexOf(cookieName);
 if (ind==-1 || cookieName=="") return ""; 
 var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(';',ind);
 if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length; 
 return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+cookieName.length+1,ind1));
}
if (ReadCookie('cookie1') != '1') { 
 setCookie('cookie1','1', frequencyCap); 
document.write("TAG POPUP-1");
}else if (ReadCookie('cookie2') != '1') { 
 setCookie('cookie2','1', frequencyCap); 
document.write("TAG POPUP-2");
}else if (ReadCookie('cookie3') != '1') { 
 setCookie('cookie3','1', frequencyCap); 
document.write("TAG POPUP-3");
}else if (ReadCookie('cookie4') != '1') { 
 setCookie('cookie4','1', frequencyCap); 
document.write("TAG POPUP-4");
}else if (ReadCookie('cookie5') != '1') { 
 setCookie('cookie5','1', frequencyCap); 
document.write("TAG POPUP-5");
}
// --> 
</script>
```

Comment: `i want the script rotate automaticly one pop'up every 60 seconds` - well, for a start, you'll need to stop using `document.write` - in fact, you should stop using it anyway!

Comment: Hi, maybe but this is the only way to make javascript popup tag work, do you have any solution ?

Comment: "javascript popup tag" - not sure what that is, all you're doing is writing "TAG POPUP-#" to the page - is there some other code that does something with this text? you can achieve adding text to the page without using document.write - unless you really need to support Netscape 1.0 or Mosaic browser of course

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple timer function. All you'll need to do is put in your code to switch the popup tags

```
var timer = setInterval(rotate, 60000);
var idx = 0;

function rotate() {
    if (idx++ < 5) {
    //Insert code to switch popup tags
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Index: " + idx;
    //  ^ demo of timer working
    if (idx >= 5)
        idx = 0;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3t7nqpg7/1/